# Do I have to replace unique values on time series dataset. but when invoke the replace, it returns the same

Tags: python, numpy, time-series, unique, isnull

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiSyT.png)

replacing unique values on time series dataset, and then replacing them nan, then replacing nan with zeros so that i can convert the column to date format then the zeros will NaT

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: df['date_fueled'].replace(unique, np.nan).                                                                                        df['date_fueled'] = df['date_fueled'].replace(np.nan, 0)
df